# Characterization of positive McLauren series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

A non-negative real polynomial can always be written as $p_1(x)^2+p_2(x)^2$, (or something like this?), where $p_i$ are real polynomials. But can we say something like this for a positive McLauren series? For example they are always equal to $\sum c_ie^{a_ix}$ with a positive sequence $c_i$, and $a_i$ is real?

Comment: Power series equal to a series of exponentials???

Comment: On the interval $(-1,1)$ the function $-\log (1-x)$ has a McLauren series with positive coefficients and it cannot be written in the stated form becuse your exponential sum takes only positive values. I think one can construct a counter-example on the whole real line too.

Comment: positive McLauren = positive function, capiche?